# PHP textarea Implode and explode with comma seperated

Tags: php, implode

I want to implode a textarea name as comma seperated to store in database. I am not getting a exact solution.

HTML code :

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="input-1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Textarea</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8"> 
          <textarea name="reg_desc" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
     </div>    
</div>
```

PHP Code :

```
$reg_desc = implode(',', $_POST['reg_desc']);
```

SQL Query :

```
$sql="INSERT into `regions` (`reg_desc`) VALUES  ('$reg_desc')";
```

Exactly if i want to insert a record in textarea like (see the screen shot)

[image]

It will store with comma seperated in database.

Comment: `comma seperated in database` is not how a db should be set up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad If the question is just about PHP processing of CSVs see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Regardless what you are doing with your database... `$_POST['reg_desc']` will not contain an `Array` from just a single textarea.

Comment: What you probably want is `implode(',', explode("\n", $_POST['reg_desc']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your solution, you have to split string with new line then replace with comma when you find new line.

`implode(',', explode("\n", $_POST['reg_desc']))`